# Merge Python and Android SL4A code

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I am trying to make automatic attendance on my android phone [which is triggered by NFC]. I have tested the following Python code separately on PC:

```
from datetime import datetime
s1 = '09:40:00'
s2 = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
s3 = datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
print ('I have arrived ['+str(tdelta)+']' 'HH:MM:SS'' late at ['+str(s3)+'].')
```

And following Android Code separately:

```
droid = android.Android
import android
number = "mycellnumber"
message = "Hello"
droid.smsSend(number, message.encode("utf-8"))
```

What I want is to merge these two codes and send the following as message(and in email body later):

```
 ('I have arrived ['+str(tdelta)+']' 'HH:MM:SS'' late at ['+str(s3)+'].')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to merge the code and now it looks like this:

```
import android
import datetime
droid = android.Android()
s1= '09:40:00'
s2= datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
s3= datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.datetime.strptime(s2,FMT) -    datetime.datetime.strptime(s1,FMT)
print ('I have arrived ['+str(tdelta)+']')
number = "XXXXXXXXXX" 
message = str(tdelta)
droid.smsSend(number, message.encode("utf"))
```